# How do I integrate VirusTotal with Nautilus?

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, nautilus

Here's a great site: https://www.virustotal.com/index.html

Does anyone have a how to/link, how to integrate a menu in Nautilus?

[image]

Like: "send file to Nautilus" when right clicking a file?

Theres an API: http://www.virustotal.com/advanced.html#publicapi

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script in bash and store under $HOME/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts.

See the [Nautilus Scripts](http://library.gnome.org/users/user-guide/2.32/gosnautilus-444.html.en) guide.  If you want more control, you might want to write a plugin using Python or C (in that case, you want to read the [answer in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848486/where-can-i-find-the-docs-of-libnautilus/5854050#5854050)).